# Java Collections.reverseOrder() vs. Comparator

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I am practicing leetcode and oftenTimes I see different ways of reversing data structures. I was wondering if there is a benefit to doing it one way vs the other?

For example to create a max heap from a PriortiyQueue i can

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> b-a);
```

or

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Is the time and space complexity the same? Should i be defaulting to use a comparator or is the collections.reverseOrder() good?

Answer (score 3):

The first `Comparator` (one with lambda) is wrong because it is subject to integer overflow (for example, with b = Integer.MIN_VALUE and a > 0, this would return a positive value, not a negative one), you should use:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> Integer.compare(b, a));
```

Which is also called by [Integer.compareTo](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b6c35ae44aeb31deb7a15ee2939156ed00b3df52/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L1468), which is called by [`reverseOrder`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b6c35ae44aeb31deb7a15ee2939156ed00b3df52/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#L5326).

As said in other answer, you should use the `reverseOrder` or `Comparator.reversed()` because it make the intention clear.

Now, for your question in depth, you should note that:

- The lambda `(a, b) -> b - a` is affected by unboxing and should be read `b.intValue() - a.intValue()` and since this one is not valid for some values due to integer overflow: it should be `Integer.compare(b.intValue(), a.intValue())`.
- The `reverseOrder` simply calls `b.compareTo(a)` which calls `Integer.compare(value, other.value)` where value is the actual value of the boxed `Integer`.

The performance difference would amount to:

- The cost of the two unboxing
- Cost of calling methods.
- The JVM optimization

You could wind up a JMH test (like the one below, based on another that I wrote for [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622027/performance-for-java-stream-concat-vs-collection-addall/41622945#41622945)): I shortened the values v1/v2 does to 3 because it takes times (~40m).

```java
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Warmup(  time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(  time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Fork(1)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode({ Mode.AverageTime})
public class ComparatorBenchmark {
  private List<Integer> values;

  @Param({ "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE, "" + Integer.MAX_VALUE, "10", "-1000", "5000", "10000", "20000", "50000", "100000" })
  private Integer v1;

  @Param({ "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE, "" + Integer.MAX_VALUE, "10", "1000", "-5000", "10000", "20000", "50000", "100000" })
  private Integer v2;

  private Comparator<Integer> cmp1;
  private Comparator<Integer> cmp2;
  private Comparator<Integer> cmp3;

  @Setup
  public void setUp() {
    cmp1 = (a, b) -> Integer.compare(b, a);
    cmp2 = (a, b) -> b - a;
    cmp3 = Collections.reverseOrder();
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void with_Integer_compare(Blackhole blackhole) {
    blackhole.consume(cmp1.compare(v1, v2));
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void with_b_minus_a(Blackhole blackhole) {
    blackhole.consume(cmp2.compare(v1, v2));
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void with_reverse_comparator(Blackhole blackhole) {
    blackhole.consume(cmp3.compare(v1, v2));
  }
}
```

Running this on:

- Windows 10
- Java 17.0.2
- AMD Ryzen 7 2700X @ 3.70 GHz

Produces the following result (I limited it to 3 values: MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE and 10 because its ETA is ~40m):

```
Benchmark                                           (v1)         (v2)  Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
ComparatorBenchmark.with_Integer_compare     -2147483648  -2147483648  avgt    5  1,113 ± 0,074  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_Integer_compare     -2147483648   2147483647  avgt    5  1,111 ± 0,037  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_Integer_compare     -2147483648           10  avgt    5  1,111 ± 0,075  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_Integer_compare      2147483647  -2147483648  avgt    5  1,122 ± 0,075  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_Integer_compare      2147483647   2147483647  avgt    5  1,123 ± 0,070  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_Integer_compare      2147483647           10  avgt    5  1,102 ± 0,039  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_Integer_compare              10  -2147483648  avgt    5  1,097 ± 0,024  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_Integer_compare              10   2147483647  avgt    5  1,094 ± 0,019  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_Integer_compare              10           10  avgt    5  1,097 ± 0,034  ns/op

ComparatorBenchmark.with_b_minus_a           -2147483648  -2147483648  avgt    5  1,105 ± 0,054  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_b_minus_a           -2147483648   2147483647  avgt    5  1,099 ± 0,040  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_b_minus_a           -2147483648           10  avgt    5  1,094 ± 0,038  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_b_minus_a            2147483647  -2147483648  avgt    5  1,112 ± 0,044  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_b_minus_a            2147483647   2147483647  avgt    5  1,105 ± 0,029  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_b_minus_a            2147483647           10  avgt    5  1,112 ± 0,068  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_b_minus_a                    10  -2147483648  avgt    5  1,086 ± 0,010  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_b_minus_a                    10   2147483647  avgt    5  1,125 ± 0,084  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_b_minus_a                    10           10  avgt    5  1,125 ± 0,082  ns/op

ComparatorBenchmark.with_reverse_comparator  -2147483648  -2147483648  avgt    5  1,121 ± 0,050  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_reverse_comparator  -2147483648   2147483647  avgt    5  1,122 ± 0,067  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_reverse_comparator  -2147483648           10  avgt    5  1,129 ± 0,094  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_reverse_comparator   2147483647  -2147483648  avgt    5  1,117 ± 0,046  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_reverse_comparator   2147483647   2147483647  avgt    5  1,122 ± 0,072  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_reverse_comparator   2147483647           10  avgt    5  1,116 ± 0,080  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_reverse_comparator           10  -2147483648  avgt    5  1,114 ± 0,052  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_reverse_comparator           10   2147483647  avgt    5  1,133 ± 0,068  ns/op
ComparatorBenchmark.with_reverse_comparator           10           10  avgt    5  1,134 ± 0,036  ns/op
```

As you can see, the score are within the same margin.

You would not gain/lose much from neither implementation, and as already said, you should use `Collections.reverseOrder()` to make your intention clear, and if not use `Integer.compare`, not a subtraction subject to integer overflow unless you are sure that each `Integer` is limited (for example, `Short.MIN_VALUE` to `Short.MAX_VALUE`).

Answer (score 1):

The asymptotics are the same, but `Collections.reverseOrder()` has several important advantages:

- It guarantees that it doesn't do an allocation.  (`(a, b) -> b - a` probably doesn't allocate, either, but `reverseOrder` guarantees a singleton.)
- It is clearly self-documenting.
- It works for all integers; `b-a` will break if comparing e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and -2 due to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the time and space complexity is the same (constant).

Using `Collections.reverseOrder()` is better because it names the order explicitly, instead of making the reader read the implementation and infer the order.

Answer (score -1):

I think time and space complexity must be same because at the end your passing the comparator in both object creations so the only difference is :-

```
//passing specified comparator
PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> b-a);

//Collection.reverseOrder will return comparator with natural reverse ordering
PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```